# object oriented programming: another way to implement state pattern?

Tags: javascript, oop, state-pattern

I need help with another solution in this  `Object-oriented design` challenge! The technical leader asked me to give another solution.

*This is the challenge*:

An Army is made up of units. A unit could be a pikeman, an archer, or a knight. A pikeman can be transformed into an archer; an archer can be transformed into a knight, and a knight can not be transformed.

*This was my solution*:

```
class Unit {}

class Pikeman extends Unit {
  transform() {
    return new Archer();
  }
}

class Archer extends Unit {
  transform() {
    return new Knight();
  }
}

class Knight extends Unit {
  transform() {
    throw new Error('a Knight can not be transformed');
  }
}

class Army {
  constructor() {
    this.units = [] // a collection of units
  }
  addUnit(unit) {
     units.push(unit);
  }
  
  transformUnits(units) {
     var unitsTransformed = units.map(u => u.transform())
  }
}
```

Although the technical leader asked me if there were another way to implement the `transform` method instead of returning a new object.

Could anyone help me to find a new solution?

Comment: Treat `a pikeman, an archer, or a knight` as different states of the same object.Then your `transform` will be *update* and not *create*.

Comment: Is there anything else these `Unit` objects can do other than to transform?

Comment: A unit can be `trained`, but I think it is not the point.  Do you think this helps?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how would I do it. I hope it solves your problem.

```js
const PIKEMAN = 0;
    const ARCHER = 1;
    const KNIGHT = 2;


    class Unit {
      // list of possible type of units, ordered by its hierarchy
      types = ["pikeman", "archer", "knight"];
      
      // current type of the unit
      current_type = 0;
      
      constructor(type = PIKEMAN){
        // by default, unit type is a pikeman 
        this.current_type = type;
      }
      
      transform(){
        // try to check, if it has a next hierarchy or not,
        let nextType = this.current_type + 1;
        
        // if its possible to transform it into the next unit type, then transform it
        if (this.types[nextType]) {
          this.current_type++;
          
          // return back the instance
          return this;
        }
        
        // get its current type on what unit this is.
        const currentType = this.types[ this.current_type ];
        
        // throw that i cannot be transformed anymore
        throw new Error("A "+currentType+" cannot be transformed")
      }
      
    }


    class Army {
      constructor(units = []) {
        this.units = units // a collection of units
      }
      addUnit(unit) {
         this.units.push(unit);
      }
      
      transformUnits() {
         return this.units.map(u => u.transform())
      }
    }


    let army = new Army([
      new Unit(PIKEMAN),  
      new Unit(ARCHER)
    ]);

    console.log(army.transformUnits());
```

Comment: thank you for your solution! although I was looking for a solution that takes the subclasses instead of using a variable with the type!

Comment: Oh okay, you actually mentioned at the title, "state pattern" which I believe handling the type of Unit when it goes transition upon transforming it to other types. 

If you are still seeking a different solution I'll try to come up with the Subclasses approach.